# Remove keys from cache

Tags: c++, memcached

I'm using [memcached and c++](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html). I want to remove all keys from server using c++ api. It would be better to remove them without list of the keys.

There is function in documentation: [memcached_dump](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_dump.html#memcached_dump_fn) and [memcached_delete](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_delete.html). First one returns the list of keys, and the second one - removes them.

But here is the quote from the docs of first function:

> memcached_dump() is used to get a list of keys found in memcached(1)
>   servers. Because memcached(1) does not guarentee to dump all keys you
>   can not assume you have fetched all keys from the server.

The first question: any ways to fetch ALL keys and the second is: how to use these functions at all. There aren't any examples in documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`memcached_flush`](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_flush.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to remove the memcached keys would be the use of basic delete command.
But as we don't know which keys to delete, you ought to keep a log of the data being set in the memcached. You could dump these log along with their time-stamp in any data-store. By this procedure you would be able to delete keys with certain rules thereby providing to better control in the delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

Logging keys is a useful way of managing cache data when you need to be able to delete a bunch of keys. In addition, using a prefix can provide a way of managing the cached data as a whole.

```
function save($key,$data,$group){
    cache_log_key($group,$key);
    cache_save($application_prefix.$key,$data);
}

function deleteGroup($group){
    $loggedKeys = cache_get_log($group);
    foreach($loggedKeys as $key){
        cache_delete($application_prefix.$key);
    }    
    cache_delete_log($group);
}
```